# when change targetSDK version from 30 to 31 Execution failed for task ':react-native-pager-view:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i use React Native,
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.3",
i got error when change
compileSdkVersion = 30  targetSdkVersion = 30
to
compileSdkVersion = 31 targetSdkVersion = 31
because google play console ask me to update target sdk version from 30 to 31

```
yarn android
yarn run v1.22.10
$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 6255 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :tp-react-native-bluetooth-printer
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed soon. For more information see: hxxp://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

The Kotlin Gradle plugin was loaded multiple times in different subprojects, which is not supported and may break the build.
This might happen in subprojects that apply the Kotlin plugins with the Gradle 'plugins { ... }' DSL if they specify explicit versions, even if the versions are equal.
Please add the Kotlin plugin to the common parent project or the root project, then remove the versions in the subprojects.
If the parent project does not need the plugin, add 'apply false' to the plugin line.
See: hxxps://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl
The Kotlin plugin was loaded in the following projects: ':react-native-pager-view', ':react-native-webview'

> Task :react-native-pager-view:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See hcxps://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
63 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 61 up-to-date
[Fatal Error] gradle-3.5.3.pom:7:3: The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".
[Fatal Error] builder-3.5.3.pom:7:3: The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".
[Fatal Error] lint-gradle-api-26.5.3.pom:7:3: The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".
[Fatal Error] gradle-api-3.5.3.pom:7:3: The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".
[Fatal Error] crash-26.5.3.pom:7:3: The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".
[Fatal Error] bundletool-0.9.0.pom:7:3: The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".
[Fatal Error] jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta04.pom:7:3: The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".
[Fatal Error] jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta04.pom:7:3: The element type "hr" must be terminated by 
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_272). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (hxxp://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (hxxp://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class com.sun.tools.javac.util.UnsharedNameTable$NameImpl)
        at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:133)
        

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-pager-view:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at hxxps://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 7s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: hxxps://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
[Fatal Error] gradle-3.5.3.pom:7:3: The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit hxxps://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```